# Why do some Global symbols require an explicit package name

Tags: perl

Why does line 18 required explicit package name in the code below?

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use feature qw<say state>;

{
    no strict;
    no warnings;

    $myRef{G4143} = 58;
    $myRef{Emily} = 8;
    $myRef{Angela} = 40;

}

#%myRef requires explicit package name
while (my ($key, $value) = each %myRef) {
    say "$key=>$value";
}

exit(0);
```

If I add the main package to %myRef on line 18, then it works

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use feature qw<say state>;

{
    no strict;
    no warnings;

    $myRef{G4143} = 58;
    $myRef{Emily} = 8;
    $myRef{Angela} = 40;

}
#added package name and now it works
while (my ($key, $value) = each %main::myRef) {
    say "$key=>$value";
}

exit(0);
```

Why is the package name required in this example?

Comment: because that's what `use strict` does; https://perldoc.pl/strict#strict-vars: "generates a compile-time error if you access a variable that was neither explicitly declared...nor fully qualified"

Comment: ... and that `no strict;` was lexically restricted to the block `{...}` in which it is (wasn't that the intent?), so after that block `strict` is in effect again and `%myRef` hasn't been declared.

Comment: Also note, the first statement involving `%myRef` inside that block does result in the creation o a _global variable_ with that name. Too bad that you can't use it outside of that block though, since it's not declared where `strict` _is_ in effect. But -- if you add another block with `no strict` you _can_ use that `%myRef` in it.  (If it is removed from the rest of the program so that it compiles under `strict` of course.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the package name because

1. `strict` is enabled *and*
2. `%myRef` has not been declared (using `my`, `our`, or `use vars`) in that scope or any enclosing scope

You *don't* need the package name in the earlier block because `strict` is turned off within that block.

If you add the line `my %myRef;` (or `our %myRef;` if you want it to be visible outside of the current file and package) before the `no strict` block, then you will no longer need the explicit package name, nor will you need `no strict` within the block.

And the `no warnings` is already superfluous, so I would recommend removing it.  There's nothing in that block that would generate a warning in any case.